# Comic short post apocalyptic : Last men on earth killed by a dead man

Tags: story-identification, comics, post-apocalyptic

Been looking for this for almost three decades now, tried googling a variety of combinations but have yet to turn up anything useful.

I read this short comic back in about '93-96 (definitely no later than '98) in what I think was a swedish comic magazine (likely collecting stuff from 2000 AD and similar). I believe the style was quite gritty and semi-realistic (like Rogue Trooper etc). It was in color, I believe.

The story is post apocalyptic, a group of humans are moving through a devastated city (I remember buildings, at least), they wear sort of futuristic environment suits (again, more similar to Rogue Trooper than modern NBC protection). Suddenly one of them gets shot from an unknown position and the rest attempt to contact the shooter to let them know that "the war is over" or something like that. I think the rest of them get picked off one by one trying to attack the enemy position until at last the final survivor gets mortally wounded moving into the house where the enemy is.

The final survivor enters the room and sees the shooter, a skeleton still grasping some sort of automated, self targetting rifle (I want to remember it looking like a modern assault rifle attached on top of a box of some sort) and the end line is something along the lines of "The last man on earth was killed, by a dead man!".

Comment: Have you try dark horse or image they do release foreign comic

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is "The Last Man!", one of Tharg's Future Shocks.  Thus as you suggested it was published in 2000AD, (prog 206).  It was written by Gary Rice and drawn by Brett Ewins.

Your description describes the entire story (it is only three pages).  Here is the last page.

[image: Last page of the story]